# Can only get one single document by id in a Firestore collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am stuck with a very strange bug and I can't understand why it is happening.
I have a collection in the Google Firestore called `previews`, in the collection, I have 4 documents that I manually inserted into the Firestore with automatically generated ids.
When I try to get the documents by id, only one of them is retrievable from the JavaScript side. I've been able to reproduce the problem with the query builder of the Firestore:

[image]

You can clearly see the documents here with their ids.
When I query `BEOEGqnl7wBXCB6G4RLP`, it works:

[image]

But when I query any other document, I get no result, even though they do exist!

[image]

I tried to change the properties of the documents, I also thought it may be some invisible space, but I checked that too. I don't see any difference between the documents, except for the data that's in them.

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have 4 documents that I *manually* inserted into the Firestore with automatically generated ids.

There's a high chance you added a *space* either at the start or end of the document ID in the data or while querying. 
To confirm if the issue is with the document ID, you can open that document in *panel view* and check the URL. The document ID should be right after `~2F` and then check for any encoded characters like `%20` in this case.

[image]

Alternatively, print the document IDs with quotes:

```
const snap = await getDocs(collection(db, "previews"))
snap.forEach((d) => console.log(`'${d.id}'`))
```

Comment: I think you are right, when I prefix the ids that don't work with an empty space in my JS code to retrieve the document, I receive it!
I still can't explain to myself how this happened, I just clicked on `Auto-ID` to generate an id and didn't touch it. Did Google add an empty space?

Comment: @ClaudeBarde I don't face this issue, perhaps try with a different browser once just to confirm.